# Added topic approved or not?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-topics

Today I created a topic "Loops" in the Bash tag (https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/drafts/35489).

I got a notification that this was approved, however I does not show up in the Bash tag. Also I got no notification for any removal or something.

When I click on the link on my reputation page I get a page not found error (https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/e/10215). I spent some time for adding documentation and it got removed without discussion or anything. It is really disappointing from seething happen.